# CSS different height div elements causing grid spacing

Tags: html, css, grid, alignment, height

This picture describes by problem better than I can put it into words. How can I get the grid to be tight **without any gaps**. I need a **CSS only solution** if there is one. I would rather not change the html if at all possible. There is a [demo set up here](http://codepen.io/coltonf93/pen/aeqfp) if you would like to try out some ideas. **Variable heights** must be **allowed** also so we can't set all the elements to the same height. Any Ideas?

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/coltonf93/pen/aeqfp)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also do this by alternating your floats. I changed some of the box css, adding box-sizing and removing the inline-block

http://jsfiddle.net/x666E/

```
.box{background-color:white;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  width:50%;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box:nth-child(2n + 0) { float: right; }
```

Comment: It's not working for me and I don't know why. Can be problem if I have `<li>` instead of `<div>` ? http://jsfiddle.net/qqLg5mLh/